# NULL handling in JPA associations without FK

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

MoldBomInfo VO

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "MACHINE_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private MachineInfo machineInfo;
```

MachineInfo VO

```
public class MachineInfo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="MACHINE_CODE")
    private String machineCode;

    @Column(name="MACHINE_NAME")
    private String machineName;

    @Column(name="STD_LEAD_TIME")
    private int stdLeadTime;

    @Column(name="FACTORY_CODE")
    private String factoryCode;

    @Column(name="MCH_GRP_CODE")
    private String mchGrpCode;
```

MoldBomInfo TABLE

[image]

MachineInfo TABLE

[image]

Error Code

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find e3view.factoryview.main.mold.model.MachineInfo with id
```

FK is not currently set.
I need to get the MACHINE_NAME of the MachineInfo table based on the MACHINE_CODE column of the MachineBomInfo table.

The problem is that MACHINE_CODE can be NULL in the MachineBomInfo table.
Therefore, when using JPA, ERROR CODE is issued.

Currently I do not have permission to operate tables.

How do I get the result I want through JPA without setting FK?

Answer (score 1):

In `JoinColumn`, if you don't provide `referencedColumnName`, default `column` will be `ID`.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "MACHINE_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "HERE_YOUR_REF_COLUMN")
private MachineInfo machineInfo;
```